# Error por dependencia cordova-plugin-firebase en ionic

Tags: android, firebase, ionic, cordova, ionic4

Tengo un proyecto con ionic 4 y al ejecutar el comando `ionic cordova build android` da un error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Entonces decidí crear una nueva app y ejecutar el comando `ionic cordova build android` de a poco mientras pasaba funcionalidades y note que la dependencia que genera el error es `cordova-plugin-firebase`, he leido mucho en internet y unos recomiendan modificar el archivo `build.gradle` que se encuentra en

> platforms > android > build.gradle

o que instale otras dependencias como `cordova-plugin-androidx` y `cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter`

he seguido muchas instrucciones pero ninguna parece funcionar, y hasta ahora la respuesta mas general que he encontrado en la comunidad es que es un error causado por una actualización muy reciente de google.

les dejo la informacion de mi proyecto:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.5.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 8 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/GustavoSanchez/Library/Android/sdk/)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Y la lista de plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me encontre con el mismo error, si es un problema causado por la actualizacion del plugin por parte de google, y si necesitas incluir los plugins de cordova-plugin-androidx y cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter, pero tambien debes de migrar el plugin de firebase de cordova-plugin-firebase a cordova-plugin-firebasex para que funcione.

los pasos que segui son estos:

```
rm -Rf platforms/android

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebase

rm -Rf plugins/ node_modules/

npm install

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex

cordova platform add android
```

tambien debes tener actualizado cordova a la version 9 o superior y la plataforma de android a la version 8 o superior.

estos pasos me funcionaron perfectamente, te dejo el enlace de la documentacion de este procedimiento.

[cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebasex)

espero te sirva compañero.

Comment: al remover cordova-plugin-firebase y agregar cordova-plugin-firebasex y en conjunto con las dependencias de cordova-plugin-androidx y cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias Andres